# I want to create array of movieclip, its index is id attribute for one node in xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have xml file, each node in it has id attribute. i want to create movieclip for each node, so the id must be index for the array of movieclip, so i can call any movieclip by its id attribute.
i do that, but i get wrong.

```
var mc: Array = new Array();
for loop
 {
var mc[id]:MovieClip= new MovieClip();
addChild(mc[id]);
 }
```

I get this error message:

> Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 33    1086: Syntax error:
>   expecting semicolon before leftbracket.)  line 33 is: var
>   mc[id]:M.......   ();

Comment: friend, i trace the name of each movieclip i created, i get instance9, instance19, instance29, instance39, instance49......, instance1909. Can I use thes name permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is written incorrectly and is missing a lot of necessary information.  Try something like this:

```
const numberOfClips:int = 20; //change as needed
var mc: Array = new Array();
for(var id:int = 0; id < numberOfClips; id++)
{
     mc[id] = new MovieClip();
     addChild(mc[id]);
}
```